# How to Terraform import an AWS Route of Route Table targeting a NAT gateway

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Given the following AWS resources:

- Route table
- Route of Route table
- NAT gateway

The following HCL code (Terraform v0.11)

```
resource "aws_route" "nat-route" {
  route_table_id         = "${var.route_table_id}"
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  nat_gateway_id         = "${var.nat_gw_id}"
}
```

The Terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route.html#import) suggest this method to import:

```
terraform import aws_route.nat-route rtb-123456ABCDF_0.0.0.0/0
```

But didn't specify the target ID for its NAT gateway, VPC peering, Internet gateway, etc. only the route table and the destination CIDR.

How can this NAT route be imported to the Terraform state?

Comment: Does your existing Route already have it's NAT gateway etc configured (in AWS)?

Comment: Yes, it is. @lxop

Answer (score 2):

Does your existing Route already have it's NAT gateway etc configured (in AWS)? If so, then Terraform will pick up all the configuration during the import. If not, then you can configure those items with Terraform after importing it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I think is risky to import, then configure and re-apply, working in a production env.

Comment: Sure. What I mean is that you don't specify the configuration of items that you are importing; the import will do that. You only need to tell Terraform which 'thing' to import. The import itself should be safe - it will only update your local tfstate. Then you can run `terraform plan` to check if your code has a configuration that matches reality